# How to import data into Fusion Table directly?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-fusion-tables

Below code is working fine. I can upload the data into Google Drive. Instead of Upload a data into Google Drive.

How to import data or ImportRows into Google Fusion Table directly? Can anyone help me and correct what I need to do.

### E.g:

```
var request = gapi.client.request({
              'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
              'method': 'POST',
              'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
              'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
              },
```

### Working Code :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var CLIENT_ID = '607567025394-rmte05500pvsoj12dsrie1cbei5te506.apps.googleusercontent.com';
      //var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
      var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables';

      /**
       * Called when the client library is loaded to start the auth flow.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
      }

      /**
       * Check if the current user has authorized the application.
       */
      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
            {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': true},
            handleAuthResult);
      }

      /**
       * Called when authorization server replies.
       *
       * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
       */
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authButton = document.getElementById('authorizeButton');
        var filePicker = document.getElementById('filePicker');
        authButton.style.display = 'none';
        filePicker.style.display = 'none';
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          // Access token has been successfully retrieved, requests can be sent to the API.
          filePicker.style.display = 'block';
          filePicker.onchange = uploadFile;
        } else {
          // No access token could be retrieved, show the button to start the authorization flow.
          authButton.style.display = 'block';
          authButton.onclick = function() {
              gapi.auth.authorize(
                  {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': false},
                  handleAuthResult);
          };
        }
      }

      /**
       * Start the file upload.
       *
       * @param {Object} evt Arguments from the file selector.
       */
      function uploadFile(evt) {
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
          var file = evt.target.files[0];
          insertFile(file);
        });
      }

      /**
       * Insert new file.
       *
       * @param {File} fileData File object to read data from.
       * @param {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
       */
      function insertFile(fileData, callback) {
        const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
        const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
        const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
          var metadata = {
            'title': fileData.name,
            'mimeType': contentType
          };

          var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
          var multipartRequestBody =
              delimiter +
              'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
              JSON.stringify(metadata) +
              delimiter +
              'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
              'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
              '\r\n' +
              base64Data +
              close_delim;

          var request = gapi.client.request({
              'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
              'method': 'POST',
              'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
              'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
              },
              'body': multipartRequestBody});
          if (!callback) {
            callback = function(file) {
              console.log(file)
            };
          }
          request.execute(callback);
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Add a file picker for the user to start the upload process -->
    <input type="file" id="filePicker" style="display: none" />
    <input type="button" id="authorizeButton" style="display: none" value="Authorize" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: corrected tags. typos.

Answer (score 0):

Fusion Tables also have a REST API. you can make the calls in the same way you are calling the Drive REST API.

For example to [import rows](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/table/importRows) you would need modify the api call and  change the path to "upload/fusiontables/v2/tables/tableId/import"
It also uses POST method.

I see you have the correct scope for fusion tables: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables

You'll also need to provide the data you want to import.

Hope this helps.